# alertdialog show an image and a title

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm doing an AlertDialog, it has an image and a title:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
builder.setTitle("Recuerda tirar del cable");
builder.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tira_cable));

builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //actions
      }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

The title is not shown:

[image]

where is the title? I can't understand!

Comment: use 72x72 icon to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this will make a difference but I don't think the extra "noise", for lack of a better term is necessary in the `.setIcon`. Try:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
builder.setTitle("Recuerda tirar del cable");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.tira_cable);

builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        //actions
      }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: same behaivour, may the title be behind the image?

Comment: @user1256477 what bucket do you have your drawable in?

Comment: @user1256477 I just copy and pasted it into my code and I was able to get the title to show just fine, though I used my own drawable that I had available and I changed `activity` in the `Builder` to `getActivity()`.

Comment: Oh and I also took out the `context.getResources().getDrawable()`

Comment: I think what might be happening is that your icon is too large and it is pushing the title text out of the layout. You could either try to use a smaller picture for your icon or maybe use the picture in the body of the dialog box.